# I am doing correlation in Jmeter. I am facing below issue to find the Regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing, correlation, post-processor

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf"
                    value="40ea7f46-799b-4ca0-b8cd-4adfba082aed" />
```

Above is the token I am getting in the request output. I am unable to replace this with a regular expression in Regular Expression Extractor of Jmeter.

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="(.+?)" />` is not working.

Please help.

Comment: Please, share  the Regular Expression Extractor configuration in JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input actually contains a newline character, then you need to account for that in your regex. Furthermore, better be explicit about the valid characters in your regex, `.+` is rarely a good thing:

```
<input type="hidden"\s+name="_csrf"\s+value="([^"]+)"\s*/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to be careful with the `spaces/newlines`.

try with following simple regex:

```
value="(.*?)"\s/>
```

If it matches more than one element, to add uniquness, you can add name attribute in the regex as follows:

```
name="_csrf"\s+value="(.*?)"\s/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another evidence for [not using regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) as they are very fragile and sensitive to minimal markup changes. The more robust and resilient solution is using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead.

- The relevant CSS Expression is `input[name=_csrf]`, use `value` as "attribute"
- The XPath query to get the value is `//input[@name='_csrf']/@value`

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide for detailed information on bypassing XSRF protection in JMeter tests